# Remover duplicidade em duas colunas

Tags: sql, oracle

Gostaria de saber como resolver a seguinte situação

tenho uma view onde o codigo do item são duplicados pela chave de outra coluna
ex:

data------cod_prod-----descricao----- chave----------------------------fornecedor

12/07/18----3---------BISCOITO------18021598014743595170---WALLMART

12/07/18----3---------BISCOITO------00060122110060115217---PAO DE ACUCAR

preciso que me retorne apenas um registro porém existem vários registros com 
esse tipo de duplicidade preciso de um registro para cada cod_produto.

ex:
data------cod_prod-----descricao----- chave-----------------------fornecedor

12/07/18----3---------BISCOITO------18021598014743595170---WALLMART

Comment: Você quer alterar o campo `cod_prod` dos registros com este campo duplicado ou deseja deletar os registros com este campo duplicado para no fim só ter 1 imputação para cada `cod_prod` ?

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que percebi. Acho que precisas algo assim. SQL Server, dá feedback se ajudou.

```
SELECT [data]
      ,cod_prod
      ,descricao
      ,(SELECT TOP 1 chave FROM [teste].[dbo].[products] B WHERE B.cod_prod = A.cod_prod) AS chave 
      ,(SELECT TOP 1 fornecedor FROM [teste].[dbo].[products] B WHERE B.cod_prod = A.cod_prod) as fornecedor
FROM [teste].[dbo].[products] A
GROUP BY A.data, A.cod_prod, A.descricao
```

Answer (score 0):

Tenta isso, espero que ajude

```
SELECT * FROM nome_tabela
    WHERE
     Coluna1 NOT IN (
        SELECT Coluna1 FROM nome_tabela
        GROUP BY Coluna1
        HAVING Count(*) > 1
     )
    And Coluna2 NOT IN (
        SELECT Coluna2 FROM nome_tabela
        GROUP BY Coluna2
        HAVING Count(*) > 1
     )
```